# Display correct components on change with selected value from dropdown?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called DropDown Single and that has an options param Object and Database. If the Object is selected then I want to show the Autocomplete component for the name Table. If Database is selected I want it to show the autocomplete named database. I have tried to cut down the code with only the components I need to be using. The onclick itself doesn't actually do anything yet but I am assuming I will need it when I want it to show the right component.

```
 <div className='Main UnitTestsAutoCompleteWrapper' style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
       <div>
         <DropdownSingle
          options={['Object', 'Database']}
          value='Object'
          name='Search for unit tests'
          onclick={onChange}
         />
       </div>
        <div style={{marginRIght: '10px'}} >
          
          <AutoCompleteSingle
            name='Table'
            label='Table'
            options={autoComplete.tablesAutoComplete}
            onChange={autoComplete.onTableAutoCompleteFieldUpdate}
            onSelect={onSelect}
            uniqueIdentifier={0}
            initialValue={targetObject}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <AutoCompleteSingle
            name='Database'
            label='Database'
            options={autoComplete.databasesAutoComplete}
            onChange={(e) => onFieldUpdate(e, 'database')}
            onSelect={onDatabaseSelect}
            uniqueIdentifier={1}
            triggerOnSelectOnBackspace
          />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a simple example to guide you, you should really read the documentation. This is all covered under Conditional Rendering:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState("cow");
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={(e) => setSelectValue(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="cow">Cow</option>
        <option value="sheep">Sheep</option>
      </select>
      {selectValue === "cow" ? <p>Cow</p> : <p>Sheep</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```